# Standard xpath syntax to find all nodes with a given name (e.g. "//nodeName") fails

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I've loaded up an XML document and I'm attempting to use xpath to find all nodes with the name "**CodeList**". For whatever reason, the xpath expression `//CodeList` provides 0 nodes, but the xpath expression `/.//CodeList` provides me with the list of correctly identified nodes. Reading through various tutorials on the Internet, `//CodeList` should be the correct syntax to do what I want.

I'm not certain as to why this is happening. The xpath expression `.` and `/.` return the same node, which seems to be the document (getNodeName returns "#document").

Someone suggested that the libraries in my classpath could be the source of the problem.

So far, the only XML-related libraries that are dependencies are:

- xmlbeans-2.3.0
- xml-apis-1.3.04
- xalan-2.7.1
- xercesImpl-2.9.1

Comment: Just a note: when I do XPathFactory.newInstance().getClass(), the class I get back is org.apache.xpath.jaxp.XPathFactoryImpl.

Comment: It is difficult to say anything certain, without seeing the source XML document. One reason may be that there is a default namespace. Selecting elements by name within a document with a default namespace is one of the most FAQ in XPath. Search for 'XPath default namespace" and you'll find many good answers.

Comment: The XML document is located at http://www.federalreserve.gov/datadownload/Output.aspx?rel=H10&filetype=zip (file is H10_struct.xml). I suspect that it may be namespace related, since searching for "//*[local-name()='CodeList']" does in fact return the correct results

Comment: offbynull, then just use one of the well-known solutions: You may use the `*[local-name() ='someName']` approach, or , better, you will register a namespace with prefix (say `"x"`) bound to the default namespace. Then just use `//x:CodeList`

Answer (score 1):

`/CodeList` and `/.//CodeList` should both return exactly the same result. If they don't, it's a bug. Both should return all the CodeList elements in no namespace. If your elements are all in a (default) namespace, both expressions should return nothing.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
"//CodeList/*/text()"
```

and you'll have all child nodes in lines